# How to prevent okular from opening the same file in new window?

Tags: gnome, okular

I use okular on a gnome desktop to open pdf files directly from zotero and then annotate them. However, sometimes it happens that I have the same file open in two different workspaces and if I annotate the same file in parallel, the annotations in one window will be lost as soon as I save the edits in the other. Is there a way to prevent okular from opening the same file in a new window if it is already open? `okular --unique` is not an option, as I can only choose the default app to open pdf files in zotero, but I cannot pass a command to the app. Is there a setting in okular somewhere or the gnome settings?

To choose the app in zotero, go to Edit -> Preferences -> General, then "Open PDFs using" and choose either "System Default" or "Custom...", which opens a file browser.